# Erro sintaxe em procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, procedure, syntax-error

Estou tentando criar uma Procedure no MySQL e está retornando erro de Sintaxe. Segue o meu código para análise:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculaIdadeCP (IN cpcaminhaoid INT) 

BEGIN 
DECLARE DataEnsaio,DataMoldagem DATETIME;

/*CORPO DO PROCEDIMENTO*/     
SET DataEnsaio = (  
                    SELECT 
                        da.DataEnsaio
                    FROM dadoscpconcreto AS da INNER JOIN cpcaminhao AS cp ON
                    da.CpCaminhaoId = cp.CPCaminhaoId
                    WHERE cp.CPCaminhaoId = cpcaminhaoid
                );

SET DataMoldagem = (
                    SELECT 
                        cp.DataMoldagem
                    FROM dadoscpconcreto AS da INNER JOIN cpcaminhao AS cp ON
                    da.CpCaminhaoId = cp.CPCaminhaoId
                    WHERE cp.CPCaminhaoId = cpcaminhaoid
                    );

IF DataEnsaio IS NOT NULL THEN 
    BEGIN
            SET (
                SELECT 
                        da.IdadeRompimento 
                    FROM dadoscpconcreto AS da INNER JOIN cpcaminhao AS cp ON
                    da.CpCaminhaoId = cp.CPCaminhaoId
                    WHERE cp.CPCaminhaoId = cpcaminhaoid
                ) = SELECT DATEDIFF(DataEnsaio,DataMoldagem);
    END;
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Continua com o erro !

Comment: Cola o código aí para eu colocar aqui no meu SQL.

Comment: O que significa esse `IF DataEnsaio` ? Você está dando um `SET` em que ? E aquele `= SELECT` no final dele ?

Comment: Estou dando um Set da diferença das duas Datas no retorno do SELECT (da.IdadeRompimento) . Mas só faço isso se o DataEnsaio não for nulo

Answer (score 0):

Tente separar o `$$` do `END` e o `;` do `DELIMITER` no fim da instrução.

```
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sem o espaço você diz que o esses caracteres fazem parte do comando e isso pode estar causando o erro.